# Can we set LOCK_TIMEOUT instance- or database-wide?

Tags: sql-server, locking, transaction, time

It is possible to change the SQL Server's default (which is `-1` or indefinite period of time) `LOCK_TIMEOUT` value session-wide.

Is it possible to set `LOCK_TIMEOUT` default value server-, instance- and/or database-wide? If not, why not?

Comment: Wouldn't "server" and "instance" be the same thing?

Comment: Probably. Really I'd like to set it database-wide or instance-wide. I do not see any sense in impossibility to change indefinite hanging on locked resource behavior or I'd like to understand why it is not configurable. Or might be I am missing this functionality

Comment: "Instance" and "server" are synonyms in this context as far as opening an instance properties shows a window titled "Server Properties". People seeking for this kind of questions will most probably use "server" keyword in their searching

Answer (score 3):

**No** it isn't possible to set this as a default and change it from -1 (no timeout).

If it needs to be changed, you have to be explicit with a call to [`SET LOCK_TIMEOUT <number of ms for timeout>`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189470.aspx).

As for *why* there is no way to alter the default, we can only speculate.  But my guess would be that the lack of a timeout would satisfy the majority of requirements for queries, and need to have a lock wait timeout is a pretty corner case scenario, requiring a simple `SET` statement.

Regardless, you're talking about client-side handling.  Not server-side.  In fact, most providers that I work with by default enforce a command timeout (i.e. `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.CommandTimeout` is set to a default of 30 seconds).  Although a bit of a nested requirement with lock requests, it's the same idea.

Comment: Thanks but speculation on satisfying the majority of requirements is wrong. The majority probably uses SQL Server as storage media of out-of-the-box applications without ability to mess with their code base. Even for home-developed apps it is hardly "corner case scenario". And I am talking about database administration ... through its server management

Comment: Give me a scenario when you would want to use a nondefault lock timeout.

Comment: It is not on scenario, it is after I set it. From the moment I set it further on

Comment: As it states in the BOL link Thomas provided it can only be set at the session level. Microsoft provides no other documented method at the database or instance level.

Answer (score 1):

Blocking leads to worker thread exhaustion. It is better to allow a lock timeout that is explicit, rather than a command timeout that is ambiguous.

Using Lock timeout set < command timeout you can tell the user they have had a collision with another session. If they reach command timeout it is just a 'heavy' statement.